# Calculating the spectrum magnitude in an area in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, spectrum

I try to FFT a set of data (they are 10 pictures, with a 'T' draw in the middle) and calculate the spectrum magnitude in given areas.

Here is my code:

```
for i=1:10
    filename = sprintf('T%d.GIF', i);
    %fourier transform and showing
    f = imread(filename);       %read in image
    z = fft2(double(f));        % do fourier transform
    q = fftshift(z);            % puts u=0,v=0 in the centre
    Magq = log(abs(q));              % magnitude spectrum
    Phaseq=angle(q);            % phase spectrum
    imagesc(log(abs(q)+1));     % Usually for viewing purposes: 
    colorbar;
end
```

[image: The outcome after fft pic]

The picture above is the outcome after running my code. And the picture below is the areas I want to calculate.

[image: areas]

I'm using

```
T(i,1)=mean(mean(Magq(1:150,300:340)))+mean(mean(Magq(260:400,300:340)))+mean(mean(Magq(190:210,160:320)))+mean(mean(Magq(190:210,320:480)));
```

to calculate the spectrum magnitude, but the result of this is always `-Inf`. This is mainly because `mean(mean(Magq(1:150,300:340)))` and `mean(mean(Magq(260:400,300:340)))` are both equal to `-Inf`.

Could anyone please give me any hints why the result is `-Inf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that some values of your `q` variable are zero, so `Magq = log(abs(q))` will return -Inf at those values. Maybe the `mean` that you are looking for should be

```
log(abs(mean(mean(q(1:150,300:340)))))
```

Otherwise, if you just want to ignore the infinities, set them all to zero

```
Magq(~isfinite(Magq)) = 0
```

Before applying the `mean` function as you did before

Comment: ye I found where I went wrong. I should ignore the -Inf since it wont't affect my final result much. Anyway thanks a lot!